# Common CSS in all HTML Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Can I include all my css in my header.html and include that common header.html in all my files or i need to give reference to the same css in all my html files? I know i can include all my JS files in a common header.html because you can put the .js files in the body tag and include the div inside a body using JQuery. But with CSS you cannot include them in body tag. All pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you *include* your `header.html` in pure HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any server side languages with your HTML, then it is not possible for you to include another external JavaScript file to your HTML page, unless it is something like PHP, where you do:

```
<?php include "header.inc"; ?>
```

If you are using pure HTML, you need to put the below stuff in all the pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to include just one single CSS file in the HTML file:

`index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

And than import all your CSS files in this one CSS file:

`style.css`

```
@import url("layout.css");
@import url("contents.css");
@import ulr("http://some.online.source/example.css");
```

You certainly put the proper names you have. This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)? Using them, you can use header as an include. You can import all css and make use of a common single css. If you make use of them, you can minify your website code as much as possible.